# How to derive the law of total probability for three or more RVs?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm confused about the generalization of the law of total probability (or sum rule) for more than two Random Variables. For two RVs, it is defined as
$$
P(X=x) = \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}P(x,y).
$$
However, I'd like to clarify how this generalizes to more than two RVs. What I've tried is a simple analogy, e.g. for three RVs:
$$
P(X=x) = \sum_{y\in \mathcal{Y}}\sum_{z\in \mathcal{Z}}P(x,y,z).
$$
I'm not sure about is whether the analogy is correct and whether some prior must be considered in between the steps of the computation, e.g. is it needed to consider $P(Y)$ if I still need to compute $P(x,y,Z)$? I'm possibly confused with the conditional form of this.

Also it causes confusion for me when I see
$$
P(X_1) = \sum_{i=2}^\ell P(X_1,X_i)
$$
because I'm not sure whether $X_i$ (i=1,\dots,\ell) can be considered different RVs or $X_i$ are instances of some RV $X$.
I'll be grateful if you can give also general advise on this theme. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with discrete random variables, $X,Y$, whose probability mass function are supported over intervals $\mathcal X,\mathcal Y$, the Law of Total Probability states:

$$\mathsf P(X{=}x)=\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}\mathsf P(X{=}x,Y{=}y)$$

Or $$P_{\small X}(x)=\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y} P_{\small X,Y}(x,y)$$

Of course this can be expanded to more such random variables.  Say by adding $Z$

$$\mathsf P(X{=}x)=\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in\mathcal Z}\mathsf P(X{=}x,Y{=}y, Z{=}z)$$

Or $$P_{\small X}(x)=\sum_{y\in\mathcal Y}\sum_{z\in\mathcal Z} P_{\small X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)$$

---

Basically the probability mass of event $\{X=x\}$ equals the sum of the probability mass of *disjoint events* $\{X=x,Y=y,Z=z\}$ for all supported values for $y, z$; because $\{X=x\}$ equals the union of all these *disjoint events*.

---

> Also it causes confusion for me when I see: $$P(X_1) = \sum_{i=2}^\ell P(X_1,X_i)$$

Indeed, in such an expression, those do not appear to be random variables at all, but rather *events*. To be clear, let us use some different letters for them. Specifically when $A$ is an event and ${\{B_i\}}_{i=1}^\ell$ is a sequence of $\ell$ *disjoint* events that partition over $A$  [that is, $A\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^\ell\{ B_i\}$ ], then:$$\mathsf P(A)=\sum_{i=1}^\ell\mathsf P(A\cap B_i)$$